# No mapping found for HTTP request with URL ___ in DispatcherServlet with name ___

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been searching a way to fix this error but couldn't find the answer.
Kept getting this error:

> Apr 06, 2018 1:40:36 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>
> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-tutorial/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'

I am running on JDK 1.8, tomcat 8.0, and running on the latest eclipse IDE.

My web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID"
        version="2.5">
    <display-name>spring-tutorial</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>offers</display-name>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My offers-servlet.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan 
            base-package="com.emenpy.spring.web.controllers">
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My OffersController.java

```
package com.emenpy.spring.web.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class OffersController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

And my home.jsp

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my directory tree:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1qp1.png)

Comment: can you post an image of the directory tree of your project and the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: @AndresDLRG I have added the directory tree in my post.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your jsp should be called "home.jsp" instead of "index.jsp"</strike>

your package name in scan is

```
<context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.emenpy.spring.web.controllers">
</context:component-scan>
```

when it should be as your directory tree shows

```
<context:component-scan 
        base-package="com.cuong.spring.web.controllers">
</context:component-scan>
```

as the scaning didn't find your controller the mapping wasn't done

Comment: Sorry a typo on my post. It's home.jsp

Comment: sorry on post, I change the name. its another typo I forgot to change. Its still same problem

Comment: @ Emenpy Nguyen I run your project in my side and it works fine